# Trouble transcribing a line of Latin from Codex Claromontanus

Tags: vulgata, transcription

I am trying to transcribe Hebrews 6 from Codex Claromontanus, but am unable to decipher two lines from verse 1:

[image: Hebrews 6:1a]

Source: https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b84683111/f907.item (see halfway down the page)

From what I can work out, the first line is "relicto icitur", but that doesn't make any sense to me. Especially when I compare to the Vulgate for these two lines:

> quapropter intermittentes inchoationis Christi sermonem

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a C, but a G:

> relicto igitur initii Chr[is]t[i] verbum

This Latin is not the Vulgate at all, but a separate Latin translation made prior to it part of what's collectively known as the Old Latin texts. (This is not to be confused with Old Latin, the form of Latin before the Classical period.)

The form of 'Christi' here is a Greek 'nomen sacrum', an abbreviation of the Greek form typically found with sacred names (hence the term).

Comment: Thanks! I've been using the Vulgate as a rough guide (my Latin is poor), and it has proven more-or-less helpful in determining the words I couldn't read or understand. The Greek on the opposing leaves I have had a much easier time with...